# I cant suspend lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, fan

I cant suspend LUbuntu 16.04.02 lts  i686 . When i suspend The fun it power off but screen still alive ( black screen with light on )
 . When i touch the touchpad turn it on and fan still not spining
Help!!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Lubuntu that you're using so we can better troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.02 lts  i686